# Tomcat cannot run on Mac

Tags: java, macos, tomcat

Tomcat suddenly cannot run on Mac as the first time when it was installed, it ran properly. Before the problem happens, there was a small upgrade of Java from 1.8.x to 1.8.x. Not sure if it causes the problem.
Have tried several solutions with searching "catalina.out: Permission denied" but the problem still exists.

[catalina.out: Permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5sog.jpg)

[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHOHo.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user trying to start the tomcat does not have the rights to write the file catalina.out in logs directory of your tomcat installation.

Most likely last time you have started the tomcat as another user.

Simplest solution is to remove the existing catalina.out, e.g. using sudo rm logs/catalina.out

Comment: Problem sovled! Thank you so much Michal!

Comment: There is a new problem, As I have already added the /bin path, if I type "startup.sh", it shows tomcat started but I still cannot load the page "localhost:8080". And then I tried 
"sudo chmod 755 /Users/ohohnick/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/bin/*.sh" then

"sudo sh startup.sh"

it gave me :

"Cannot find ./catalina.sh
The file is absent or does not have execute permission
This file is needed to run this program"

But I have the catalina.sh in the bin folder...

Comment: I would suggest to re-install the tomcat under the user who is going to start it, i.e.  ohohnick in your case. You just download zip or tar.gz archive, unpack it and start the tomcat. It runs out of the box this way.

Comment: Yes Michal. I just deleted the Tomcat 8 version and downloaded a 7. Now it's always working. Thanks for your help again.